# How do I solve level 6 question 52 in Think Different?

Tags: think-different

I'm stuck on level 6 question 52 - it's a rectangular grid;

```
4  9  13 5  86 2  7  
82                9
79                24
6                 63
35                18
1  6  37 8  49 2  ?
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

**The answer is 5**

You will notice that the top row contains the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, although not in that order. The bottom row also contains these numbers, following the same rule, but is missing a 5.

You will also notice that the exact same rules apply to the left column, and would also apply to the right hand, with the inclusion of a 5.